# Maximo Anywhere 7.6 - Work Order Execution app - Work Order Details Screen is disabled or frozen (in Preview/Mobile Simulator)

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I just finished installing, building and deploying Maximo Anywhere 7.6 apps in a guest VM (Win2012).

When I did the preview of work execution app (from the operations console), it lets me login and lists the work orders. But when I click/tap a work order, the work order detail screen is shown but the entire workorder detail screen is disabled/frozen.

In Maximo 7.6: The user (miller) does have a labor record, it also has read/write access to the WOTRACK app and is part of ANYWHERE_TECHNICAN security group. It also has the access to the SITE of the workorder (via another security gorup).

Have a look at the screen shot : [work order detail screen - frozen/disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMf9x.png)

Any answers/pointers is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a developer console log from the browser? I THINK this is a bug that is resolved that affects Chrome. Installing Chromium may help or getting the fix for Anywhere. https://sourceforge.net/projects/crportable/files/?source=navbar Version 44 or earlier. 44.0.2383.0 is the one that I was guided to from Bruno here:
http://maximodev.blogspot.co.uk/2016/03/maximo-anywhere-simulator-issues-with.html

Comment: Thanks Bill, It actually worked with Firefox. I will try with Chromium if I get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Firefox and it works !!